# Reduce width of one subplot when showing multiple y- axis spines with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, charts

I have a figure containing three subplots, arranged in a single column. One of these plots uses 3 y-axis spines on the right side. I followed [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-multiple-yaxis-with-spines-py) to insert multiple right axis spines on the subplot.

My problem is that by adding the extra spines, all subplots in the figure became smaller in the x direction. This changed the width of all three subplots, which left unused space to the right of the other subplots.

How can I adjust the width of just the one subplot when adding additional spines on the y-axis?

Below is a simplified example which produces the same problem shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNRh0.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# set up a set of three subplots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 11))

ax_1_l = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
ax_1_r = ax_1_l.twinx()

ax_2_l = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
ax_2_r = ax_2_l.twinx()

ax_3_l = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
ax_3_r = ax_3_l.twinx()


# add additional axes to the middle subplot as per tutorial
def make_patch_and_spines_invisible(ax):
  ax.set_frame_on(True)
  ax.patch.set_visible(False)
  for sp in ax.spines.values():
    sp.set_visible(False)

ax_2_r_2 = ax_2_l.twinx()
make_patch_and_spines_invisible(ax_2_r_2)
ax_2_r_2.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.05))
ax_2_r_2.spines['right'].set_visible(True)

ax_2_r_3 = ax_2_l.twinx()
make_patch_and_spines_invisible(ax_2_r_3)
ax_2_r_3.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.1))
ax_2_r_3.spines['right'].set_visible(True)

# display the plots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Sample Output Image from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDAkB.png)

matplotlib version 2.1.2

Comment: Hi Evan, can you please share the working code so that we can reproduce the figure and try help providing solution?

Comment: Specifically a [mcve]

Comment: I will try to reduce the large program into a shorter script which shows the same problem. I will have to replace the real data with some sample.

Comment: Sample data is fine (although I don't think this has anything to do with the data, so perhaps just creating empty subplots might be enough..)

Comment: I've added a simple code example without any data, as DavidG suggested

Comment: Now you have 3 solutions :) That's why I asked to share the code

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. They all seem to solve my problem. I'm going to poke around and figure out which one works best in the context of my larger program before accepting a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another workaround to your problem using `gridspec` where you also have to manually set the right hand limit of your middle plot. But you stick here to 3 rows and 1 column format like you did in your original code. Just replace your code before the function definition by the following lines:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)

ax_1_l = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax_3_l = plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax_1_r = ax_1_l.twinx()
ax_3_r = ax_3_l.twinx()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
gs.update(right=0.85)  # This is the part where you specify the bound
ax_2_l = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax_2_r = ax_2_l.twinx()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this solution because it fits well with my code structure. David and John also provided working solutions with the limited example code that they saw.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer would be to use matplotlibs `subplot2grid` feature. Downside is it won't automatically adjust the sizes, you will have to manually do it..

Replace the creation of the subplots with:

```
ax_1_l = plt.subplot2grid((3, 11), (0, 0), colspan=11)
ax_2_l = plt.subplot2grid((3, 11), (1, 0), colspan=10)
ax_3_l = plt.subplot2grid((3, 11), (2, 0), colspan=11)

ax_1_r = ax_1_l.twinx()
ax_2_r = ax_2_l.twinx()
ax_3_r = ax_3_l.twinx()
```

I have made a grid with 3 rows and 11 columns, and then set the `colspan` so that subplot 2 is slightly smaller than the other 2 to leave room for the spines. (again a trial and error method so not a perfect solution)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Axes.set_position()` to adjust the position/size of individual subplots. Since you only want to change the upper x value, you can do something like:

```
bb = ax_1_l.get_position()
bb.x1 = 0.97
ax_1_l.set_position(bb)
bb = ax_3_l.get_position()
bb.x1 = 0.97
ax_3_l.set_position(bb)
```

to change the right edge of the first and third subplots.